# Setting Binding Offset (Gutter) in apa6 Class

Tags: margins, apa-style, apa6

How can I set binding offset (gutter) manually in the apa6 class in my thesis? I tried geometry package but it gave clash error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours search and 'trial-and-error', I found out that `apa6` class automatically loads geometry package. So when we load it separately, it produces the clash error. All we need to do is to add **\geometry{bindingoffset=0.4in}** in the preamble and the binding offset (gutter) will be set. For example:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\geometry{bindingoffset=0.4in}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```